# Windows Kaoriya vim で Chocoratey でインストールした Anaconda3 Pathが通らない

Tags: python, vim

Window7 32Bit の Kaoriya vim で *.py を開くと以下のような3つのエラーがでます。
Anaconda3 を Chocoratey でインストールし (C:\tools\Anaconda3) ユーザー環境変数に
Pathを加えても状況が変わりません。

Vim側の設定が不足していると考えています。
アドバイスの程お願い致します。

環境変数は以下です

[image: 環境変数]

エラ－は以下です

function jedi#init_python の処理中にエラーが検出されました:
行    7:
Error: jedi-vim failed to initialize Python: jedi-vim requires Vim with support for Python 2 or 3. (in function jedi#init_python[3]..128_init_python, 行 52)

E370: ライブラリ python27.dll をロードできませんでした
E263: このコマンドは無効です,ごめんなさい: Pythonライブラリをロードできませんでした.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

まず初めに、KaoriYa版のVimは python.org で配布されている Python 2.7 もしくは 3.5 と組み合わせて使うことを想定しています。そのため Python 3.6 を利用している Anaconda3 と組み合わせて使うことはできません。2.7 ベースである Anaconda2 との組み合わせであれば動く可能性がありますが、やはり基本的にはトラブルがあると考えるほうが良いでしょう。

ただしエラーを見る限り問題は別途インストールされているはずの jedi-vim により発生していると思われます。仮に jedi-vim だけ使えれば良い = Anaconda との連携をフルに活用できなくてもよいのであれば、別途 Python 3.5 もしくは  2.7 をインストールし環境変数 PATH を通すことで利用できる可能性があります。

また Vim のオプション `'pythonthreedll` もしくは `pythondll` を適切に設定することで、 自前でインストールした Python へ PATH を通さないでも利用できる可能性があります。この設定方法については、 http://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-ja/if_pyth.html#python-dynamic を参照してください。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。
ご教授を基に python.vim に 
`set pythonthreedll="C:\tools\Anaconda3\python36.dll"`
を追加したところE370、E263は発報されなくなりました。
しばらく様子を見ます。

Comment: 経過観察の結果以下のように対処しましたので報告致します。

1. "C:\Python35" に "Python3.5" をインストール
2. 環境変数に以下を追加 
    ```PYTHONHOME=C:\tools\Anaconda3\pkgs\python-3.5.2-0```
    ```PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONHOME%\libs```